# Outlook 2007: Create a message rule that detects autoforwarded messages and handles them

Tags: email, outlook, rules, forward

I'm looking for kind of the opposite of creating a rule to auto-forward
emails. I want to create a rule that acts on RECEIVED auto-forwarded emails,
but not any that were manually forwarded or replied to by the same person.

E.g. Jim forwards me all emails with "blah" in the subject, and I want to
move those auto forwards to my "Jim's auto-forwards" folder, but if he
forwards me a message manually that says "blah" but he adds his own comments,
I want it to stay in my inbox.

Outlook seems to know that it is auto forwarded, as it shows up
as such when you view the email. Just above the "From" section but
just below the ribbon, it says something like:

```
"This message was AutoForwarded."
```

However I haven't found any option to create a rule filtering these.

Answer (score 2):

Our exchange server (Outlook maybe?) adds the following headers when auto-forwarding:

```
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-MS-Exchange-Generated-Message-Source: Mailbox Rules Agent
```

(Visible by opening an email and viewing the message "Properties" to see the headers) These appear to be what Outlook is using to detect that a message was AutoForwarded (or at least coincide)

And Outlook/Exchange 2013 has the filter option "with specified words in the message header"

I have used a rule that looks similar to the following to successfully move only "blah" subject messages autoforwarded from "Jim" to a specific folder:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
from 'jim@example.com'
 and with 'blah' or 'blurg' in the subject
 and with 'auto-generated' or 'Auto-Submitted' in the message heade
move it to the 'Jims auto-forwards' folder
```

And this has appeared to prevent any that he's manually forwarded from being processed by the same rule.

Comment: I have found that this one works reliably on our exchange server.

Answer (score 2):

Our Exchange Server adds the following header for Auto Forwarded and Auto Replies

```
X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop: abc@company.com
```

where **abc@company.com** is the email of the person auto forwarding the email.

I use MS Outlook 2010 in which i have setup a rule ->

`From: abc@company.com
    and with 'X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop: abc.xyz@company.com' 
     or 'X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop: abc.XYZ@company.com' in the message header
     move it to the 'xyz' folder`

i have checked **abc.xyz@company.com** as well as **abc.XYZ@company.com** in message header as in some auto Fwd/Re email header the Lastname of the sender was uppercase.

*Note: as mentioned before this rule applies to all Auto Forwarded and Auto Replies (e.g Out of office/ vacation auto replies) from that person. Manual Fwd/RE emails are not filtered*

Comment: Works for me in Outlook 2016

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think rules can do this.

Try some VBA. **untested**

Edit 2013 02 26

Put the code in ThisOutlookSession http://www.slipstick.com/outlook-developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/

Here are some references so you can debug if necessary.

NewMailEx: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb147646(v=office.12).aspx

AutoForwarded Property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867162.aspx

```
    Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim varEntryIDs
    Dim objItem
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    varEntryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(varEntryIDs)
        Set objItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(varEntryIDs(i))

        'Debug.Print "NewMailEx " & objItem.Subject

        If objItem.SenderName = "Jim Smith" Then

            If objItem.AutoForwarded then

              Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
              Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

              ' Assumes destination folder is directly under the Inbox
              Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Jim AutoForwarded")
              objItem.Move myDestFolder

            End If
        End If

   Next
   Set objItem = Nothing
   Set myDestFolder = Nothing
   Set myInbox = Nothing
   Set myNameSpace = Nothing
   End Sub
```

Comment: How do I add this to my Outlook so that it would be run automatically when I receive an email?

Comment: @dstronczak I added a link to the describe where the code goes.

Comment: There was some sort of error in this line: `If objItem.SenderName = "MyCollegueName" Then`

Comment: @dstronczak Select an item from Jim. Enter ?ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).SenderName in the Immediate Pane.